# Uninstalling Steam when uninstall.exe is missing

Tags: windows, windows-10, uninstall, steam

When installing Steam I changed the installation directory to one on an external drive (bad idea, I know). Now that I want to uninstall it I thought I would simply use Programs and Features as usual, but the registry entry for the uninstaller points to a file (on the external drive) that doesn't exist, and having checking my daily backup logs, apparently never did.

I have gone through *all* `.exe` files on the disk (and again, the backup logs too), and am absolutely certain the uninstaller simply isn't (and never was) there i.e the uninstaller is missing.

I have deleted the Steam folder on my external drive, so most of the files (if not all) should be gone now, but I am really annoyed that all of the Registry entries, and any files it put on my C drive, are still there.

Is there any way, short of reinstalling Steam, of getting rid of everything?

Comment: Why don’t you want to reinstall Steam again at the same location?

Comment: @DanielB The reason I wanted to remove Steam from that drive was that the drive in question is painfully slow, so a full installation takes hours. I am just hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Why don't you just reinstall Steam on the C: drive?

Comment: Steam itself is quite small, you should be able to reinstall it in reasonable time. Alternatively, you could make another drive appear at that location, install there and then copy uninstall.exe over.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I would try:

- Download the Steam-Installer and just reinstall, then uninstall.
- Sometimes the installer actually also comes with an uninstall-option, so you could try that if it's there.
  Hope I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use iobit uninstaller which I believe doesn't require a uninstall.exe and select "force uninstall". I've used this when programs didn't have an uninstall.exe, hope this helps.

edit:
You could also go to C:/program files(x86)/steam and delete everything there or just re-run the steam installer and select reinstall

Comment: Deleting the program folder is a bad advice. If one folder was everything that a program installation changes in your system, we'd be using ZIPs instead of installers.

Comment: Instead of iObit Unisntaller, you can use **[BCUninstaller](https://www.bcuninstaller.com/)**, its free and open-source.

Comment: @gronostaj, As far as Steam goes there is just an install folder, some shortcuts, and a couple registry keys. It's completely OK to delete all of those manually and remove the install info with something like iobit uninstaller.